# RegEx for enforcing and finding the last match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am trying to extract a part of a name from a string. I almost have it, but something isn't right where I am using a positive lookahead.

Here is my regex: `(?=s\s(.*?)$)`

I have marked all the results I want with **bold** text.

> Trittbergets **Ronja**
>
> Minitiger's **Samanta Junior**
>
> Björntorpets **Cita**
>
> Sors Kelly's **Majsskalle**

The problem is that `Kelly's Majsskalle` gets returned, when it should only select `Majsskalle`.

Here is a link to *regex101* for debugging:
https://regex101.com/r/PZWxr7/1

How do I get the lookahead to disregard the first match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enforce regular expression engine to find the last match using a dot-star:

```
^.*s\s(.*)$
```

A `.*` consumes everything up to a linebreak immediately then engine backtracks to match the next pattern.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/F8oBx6/3)

or use a tempered dot:

```
s(?= ((?:(?!s ).)+)$)
      ^^^^^^^^^^
  Match a byte only if we are not pointing at a `s[ ]`
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/F8oBx6/2)

**Note**: the former is the better solution.

Comment: This works perfectly. So what I needed was basically the first part being greedy. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a lookahead. Just try this:

```
.*s\s(.*?)$
```

Comment: You can omit the question mark as `.*` will already match until the end of the string and will then backtrack until the first `s\s`. Then you could just take `(.*)$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird true! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The lookahead should be used to determine the start of a capture or the end of a capture. To start the capture **after** the first capture, you need to use a lookbehind - this ensures the text BEFORE the capture is that search pattern.

Update your pattern on regex101 to this and you'll see the difference:

```
(?<=s\s).*?$
```

**Edit** - my bad, I didn't spot that last line.

You can also include a **negative** lookahead to ensure that there's not another word that ends in `s` in the next match:

```
(?<=s\s)(?!.+?s\s).*?$
```

This solves the issue with the last line.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi see updated answer - I've fixed the last line by ensuring there are no more instances of `s\s` in the capture